# How to create a collapsible Webform form?

Tags: 7, webforms

I'd like to make a webform collapsed by default, and have a Sentence/paragraph at top of the page with a checkbox next to it. Upon ticking the checkbox I would like the webform to be displayed.

Similar to Form 2 - Adding Fieldsets on this site: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/form/dynamic.html

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: you can use #states property of drupal's FORM API or you can look into MultiStep Forms module

Comment: Thank you @PreritMohan
WHich of those is a simpler solution and suitable for someone with little php knowledge?

Comment: Also @PreritMohan
If I went with the form api solution, would I be able to reuse the webform form? Or would I need to construct my own form that would look something like this: http://drupal.org/node/751826

Comment: See the webform also uses FORM API, it's just that webform makes work easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the easy way would be to go through FORMS API http://drupal.org/node/37775

You may also look into MultiStep module once you are done with the FORM API overview.

Below are some links that you can follow:-

1. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EgGhUN2zKw4
2. http://randyfay.com/states
3. Search youtube/drupalize.me/buildamodule.com for more Form API tutorials.
4. http://tedbow.com/content/drupal/webform-conditional-demo-form

Please go through Form Api first.

Comment: Thank you @PreritMohan

I too would like to know how I can achieve the form functionality demonstrated on http://tedbow.com/content/drupal/webform-conditional-demo-form.

Will I need to rewrite the whole form and put it into a new module? Or just add the code snipped around my existing form (but how?) in order to make it collapsed by default?

Comment: Ok, I'm blind. I just realised that it's actually a module. YAY. Hope it does what I need. THanks again.